# What does the term 'Golden Clime' refer to in the following paragraph?

Tags: obscure-terms

There was once a boy who loved to go to school, and it was no great wonder, for he lived in a golden age and in a **golden clime**.

Please note that the aforementioned paragraph is taken from the book 'Stories from Plato' which was first published in 1896.

Comment: @sumelic I seek for the term 'golden age' in the dictionary, and here is what I have received.
'golden age' (noun): a period of ​time, sometimes ​imaginary, when everyone was ​happy, or when a ​particular ​art, ​business, etc. was very ​successful.

Quite regrettably​, I could not find any meaning attached to the term 'golden clime,' but instead I saw that the same term was used by Sir William Blake for his poem ''Ah! Sun-flower!''

Comment: @sumelic I have already sought for the word 'clime' in the Oxford English Dictionaries, and here is what I found.
'clime' (noun---usually climes) A region considered with reference to its climate.  
What I cannot conceive of is the sentence 'He lived in a golden clime.'
Does it assert the fact that he lived in a region where the weather was absolutely fine?
Thank you for making an essay to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the *OED*, the word *clime* used to be synonym for climate, but it is now largely poetical and has taken on the meaning of a particular region, often associated with that region's climate.  As in the phrase "sunny climes."

So "in a golden age and in a golden clime" means in an idyllic time and place.

Answer (score 3):

*Clime* is variously defined as *a place with a certain climate* ([MMD](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/clime)), or *a place in reference to its climate* ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clime)), or *a ​place where the ​weather is different in a ​particular way* ([CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/climes)), or indeed to a [climate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clime) itself (MW).

*Clime* in contemporary English is limited to poetic, or at least literary uses; meteorologists and travel agents do not customarily speak of *climes*. But with that in mind, know that *clime* is not limited to literal references to geographic locations and their weather, but can refer to the metaphorical meanings of *climate*— *a prevailing condition or set of attitudes in human affairs* ([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=climate)).

*Golden* generally refers to some apotheosis or ideal: not only a *golden age* but the *golden touch*, a *golden voice*, and so on. (Descriptions that refer to the actual metal are simply *gold*, like *gold coins* or *gold jewelry*).

Thus, a *golden clime* refers to perfect social conditions, or an ideal intellectual atmosphere, or generally the best possible society for the boy to have lived in.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into this matter. I recently started reading classics, hence I believe such terms will be frequently met;  since your description is absolutely coherent, I would not be confused if I meet such terms. 
Thank you very much!